# How to refresh aws-cognito refresh token using aws amplify in angular 2 or greater

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, angular10

#### **Summary of the project:**

In one of my project, I am using google login to login a user into my application. It's backend is **serverless (AWS)**.

Frontend has been created using **Angular 10**, and am using **AWS cognito federated login** for google login. In angular I am using **aws-amplify npm package** for interacting with aws.

I am using **response type = code** in aws-amplify configuration and am getting idtoken, accesstoken and refreshtoken once user logs in.

I am using **Auth.currentSession()** to get a new idtoken, accesstoken if they expires.

Expiry time of idtoken and accesstoken is **5** minutes.
Expiry time of refreshtoken is **60** minutes.

***Note -*** Above expiration time has been kept as minimum for testing purpose.

---

#### **Problem:**

Once my refresh token expires then I receive the message "Refresh Token has expired" on calling **Auth.currentSession().**

I want to know, is there a way to generate a new refresh token or increase/refresh the expiration time (for another 60 minutes) before it expires?